# How to measure water heater temperature?

Tags: sensor, thermistor

I'm building a summer cottage and plan to add some sensors for monitoring system health, with a Raspberry Pi and/or Arduino. Specifically, since electricity is not always available there, I'd like to measure the **water temperature in a stock water heater** (50..100 litres, 13..26 gallons) that doesn't have any extra connectors to use, eg. a Jäspi 30 or 60 litre model ([pdf](http://www.kaukora.fi/sites/default/files/kaukorafiles/EN_brochures/Jaspi_Water_heaters_brochure_EN.pdf)).

What kind of sensor should I get? How do I plug/plumb it securely?

Some notes:

- I'm aiming for a "ballpark" accuracy, maybe something like ±5°C..±10°C (±9..±18°F)
- I'm not planning to *control* the water temperature, just for logging
- I'd rather not damage the heater or its insulation
- I'd prefer a solution that would not void my house insurance (in case of an unrelated water damage)
- It doesn't have to look pretty :)

Comment: Wireless, battery-powered temperature sensor in a blob of silicone.

Comment: @Ignacio you'd have to remove the cover to mount it on the internal tank though I'd assume, these sorts of tanks usually have a big air gap between the tank and outer case

Comment: Have a look at the LM35 sensor. Works on 4 to 30 V. It gives out 10 mV/°C. Strap one or more at various levels to the side of your tank.

Comment: @Hayman: Or just drop it right in.

Comment: I guess it all depends on if you can get inside it or not, or if voiding tank warranty is a concern

Comment: Maybe encapsulted 1-wire temp sensor, if the RPi/Arduino is at short distance.

Comment: https://partofthething.com/thoughts/adding-temperature-sensors-to-a-hot-water-heater/ This looks to be the wheel you are wanting.

Answer (score 3):

Electric water heater thermostats get their reading by being mounted to the outside surface of the tank behind the insulation.  In my opinion this is the ideal location to also mount a thermocouple to measure temperature since it is identical to the control point.  Any temperature differential (actual vs. measured water temp) should be identical to that sensed by the adjacent thermostat (upper or lower).  Just take the access panel off to expose heating elements and thermostats.

Answer (score 2):

I need a similar setup for recirculating the hot water in the boiler through an adjacent solar water heater tank. This would increase the storage capacity of the system as it moves heat to the boiler when the temperature of the solar water tank exceeds the temperature of the boiler.  In my case I'm more interested in the temperature at the bottom of the tank.
A possible solution would be to replace the drain valve with a "T" such that one "path" goes to the tank straight and the other one forms a 90 degree angle. On the straight through path insert an immersion well for the thermocouple on the other path the drain valve.  All standard parts and no holes to drill.  The immersion well will constrict the flow to the drain valve a bit which is not really an issue on the drain port. For the hot water port it might still work with a 1/2 inch immersion well on a 3/4 pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Consider tapping into the hot water outlet pipe with a 'T' and having a sensor that protrudes down into the tank. It should be a straight run down into the hottest water at the top of the tank.

The only way I would consider this is with a compression fitting on the T and a thick-walled welded-end stainless steel (eg. 316 SS) tube containing the sensor going down into the tank.

The T-fitting and sensor and seals will be subject to your water system pressure (and likely some water-hammer impulses) and failure *will* cause water to spill out continuously, possibly causing a lot of (tens of thousands of dollars' worth or more) damage.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to put the temperature sensing device inside the water heater, which as the comments indicate, will either be difficult, or void the warranty, or both.

I would think the temperature of the water in the hot water line immediately adjacent to the hot water heater would be a close enough approximation.  Put a T-coupling between the hot water heater and the hot water line, and at the "bottom" end of the T, you can screw in a cap in which you have drilled a hole for the temperature measuring device, sealed with epoxy or something similar.

Comment: I had a similar thought, but looking at the datasheet, depending on whether it has a mixer or not it you wouldn't be able to measure the hot water. It also depends if the hot water line has a tap on it or not which means you would need to turn it on to measure the temperature

Comment: That's why I said it could be a good enough approximation (which the OP was looking for).   If placed immediately adjacent to the outlet, there should be pretty good heat conduction between the inside of the water heater and the pipe, regardless of whether water is flowing.

Comment: I guess another alternative is using some thermal epoxy to attach a sensor directly to the pipe before the mixer/stop taps but then it becomes a bit messy

Comment: Just use a "Surface" thermocouple attached to the hot water exit pipe as near to the heater as possible.  Attach the T/C with a hose clamp, wrap some insulation around it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'd be willing to do this in a house I own would be to tap off of the existing thermostat, or to replace it by a smart thermostat that's web enabled, like [this](http://www.techhive.com/article/2849816/smart-appliance/the-aquanta-smart-water-heater-controller-promises-to-slash-your-energy-bill.html).

Any drilled hole that you put in on your own is likely to eventually fail.  Indeed, you should assume it will, and plan accordingly.  If you want something robust, you should talk to a plumber.

I suppose you should ask yourself if you want to measure the tank temperature, in which case you should go to the consumer market, or if you'd like to build something that will measure the temperature.  If the latter, I'd advise finding some other project, as some projects are just not DIY friendly.